# How to override Controller in Magento2?

Tags: magento2

I want to override the Controller behaviour of the existing `Magento/*` module. I want to create my own `Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php`-implementation.

1. How can I do this?
2. Dependency Injection seems to be good thing for model classes but what about Controllers? Can I inject my own LoginPost controller class somewhere so that some object will use my own implementation?

Comment: If I could use router to just route customer/account/loginPost into my Controller it would be nice. But again, how to define this in routes.xml ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [**Magento2's Plugins**](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) feature for this.

> Magento enables you to change, or extend, the behavior of any
>   original, public method in any Magento class. You can change the
>   behavior of an *original method* by creating an extension. These
>   extensions use the `Plugin` class and are therefore referred to as
>   plug-ins.

Write the following in your module's `app/code/YourNamespace/YourModule/etc/di.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
   <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost">
       <plugin name="yourModuleAccountLoginPost" type="YourNamespace\YourModule\Plugin\Customer\LoginPost" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
   </type>
</config>
```

Create a new file named `app/code/YourNamespace/YourModule/Plugin/Customer/LoginPost.php` and write the following code in it:

```php
<?php

    namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Plugin\Customer;

    class LoginPost
    {
        public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject, \Closure $proceed)
        {
            // your custom code before the original execute function
            $this->doSomethingBeforeExecute();

            // call the original execute function
            $returnValue = $proceed();

            // your custom code after the original execute function
            if ($returnValue) {
                $this->doSomethingAfterExecute();
            }

            return $returnValue;
        }
    }
?>
```

Similarly, you can also use `beforeExecute()` & `afterExecute()` functions in the above class. Have a look at [this link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) for details.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution after some investigation ;-).

This resource was very helpful: https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule.

Sample module for this solution is here: 
https://github.com/nuclearhead/M2OverrideAction

The effect is that if you go to URI `/customer/account/login`, method from custom module will be fired instead of the default method from `Magento_Customer` module, and URL will remain the same. Of course, you can do the same with `loginPost` action.

I did this with `Router` class override in `di.xml`. I simplified tzyganu's SampleNews module version to clarify the solution. `Router` class checks what URI returns the `$request->getPathInfo()` method, and then sets new configs to `$request`:

```php
$request->setModuleName('overrideaction')
      ->setControllerName('view')
      ->setActionName('index');
$request->setDispatched(true);
$this->dispatched = true;
return $this->actionFactory->create(
    'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward',
    ['request' => $request]
);
```

The `etc/frontend/di.xml` of my custom module:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="customer" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">MiniSamples\OverrideAction\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">9</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```